# How to use a nested json-based formation value in the jQuery.dataTables？

Tags: datatables

Now suppose I have a json data formation like this following:

*{
               "ServiceName": "cacheWebApi",
               "Description": "This is a CacheWebApiService",
               "IsActive": true,
               "Urls": [{ "ServiceAddress": "http://192.168.111.210:8200", "Weight": 5, "IsAvailable": true },
                   { "ServiceAddress": ",http://192.168.111.210:8200", "Weight": 3, "IsAvailable": true }]
           }*

Now what worries me is that the "Urls" is another nested json formation. So how to bind this value to the datatables? And have you got any good ideas (e.g：something like I only wanna show all the ServiceAddress)...

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
var data = [{
    "ServiceName": "cacheWebApi",
    "Description": "This is a CacheWebApiService",
    "IsActive": true,
    "Urls": [
        {
            "ServiceAddress": "http://192.168.111.210:8200",
            "Weight": 5,
            "IsAvailable": true
        },
        {
            "ServiceAddress": ",http://192.168.111.210:8200",
            "Weight": 3,
            "IsAvailable": true
        }
    ]
}];
$(function() {
    var table = $('#example').dataTable({
        "data": data,
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": "ServiceName"
            }, {
                "data": "Description"
            }, {
                "data": "IsActive"
            }, {
                "data": "Urls[0].ServiceAddress"
            }, {
                "data": "Urls[0].Weight"
            }, {
                "data": "Urls[0].IsAvailable"
            }, {
                "data": "Urls[1].ServiceAddress"
            }, {
                "data": "Urls[1].Weight"
            }, {
                "data": "Urls[1].IsAvailable"
            }
        ],
    });
});
```

You should put your data in an array though. Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/ww68986b/)

**EDIT**

IF the number of Urls isn't defined then you could do something like this:

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
    "data": data,
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "ServiceName"
        }, {
            "data": "Description"
        }, {
            "data": "IsActive"
        }, {
            "data": "Urls",
            "render": function(d){
                return JSON.stringify(d);
            }
        }
    ],
});
```

I guess that that isn't brilliant but you could do almost anything to that function, for instance:

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
    "data": data,
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "ServiceName"
        }, {
            "data": "Description"
        }, {
            "data": "IsActive"
        }, {
            "data": "Urls",
            "render": function(d){
                return d.map(function(c){
                    return c.ServiceAddress
                }).join(", ");
            }
        }
    ],
});
```

Comment: But I don't know how many elements in the data. This is a group

Comment: I've updated my answer. Basically if you don't know how many you're dealing with you can iterate over them all. As long as the `render` function returns a string then you can do as you see fit... alter the styling if `IsAvailable` is false... add a weighting system for `Weight`... the world's your lobster! ;-)